# View 2 above view 1. Refer attached image

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview

There are 2 views "view1" & "view2".

view1 on left side & view2 on right.

First view1 is displayed & then on button press view2 is called. view2 should be above view 1 but view1 should be disable and when user click on view1 then view2 disappear and view1 highlighted.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is, as a simple solution:

When `View1` is Pressed to Animate `View2` into place, overlay a transparent `UIButton` over `View1`. This will cover all the subviews of `View1` and when the area is selected, you animate `View2` out of place and highlight `View1` and remove the transparent button.

Hope this makes sense !

**UPDATE:** Decided to provide a brief example, as it will probably make more sense.

```
-(void)onView1ButtonPress {

      UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      [button setFrame:[view1 bounds]];
      [button addTarget:self action:@selector(activateView1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
      [view1 addSubview:button];

     /* your other code to bring View2 into view */ 
     ....
}

-(void)activateView1:(id)sender {

     UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
     [button removeFromSuperview];

    /* your code to make View1 Active and Animate View2 out */
     ....


}
```

Comment: Updated my answer to show a visual example of achieving this, hope it makes sense and helps. If it does, would greatly appreciate if you marked it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its is little complicated to understand but as per i understand , u are creating to 2 view and u wanna to make there user interaction enable / disable .so,
1. set tag

> btnForView1.tag = 1;
>    btnForView2.tag = 2;

//create an another imageView at same fram size of view1 and set transparent image on it. 
2. method

> -(IBAction) btnPressed:(id)sender
>
> {
>
> ```
> UIbutton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
> if(btn.tag == 1)
> {
>    view2.userInteraction = NO;
>    view1.userInteraction = YES;
>    transprantImageView.hidden = NO;
> }
> else
> {
>    view1.userInteraction = NO;
>    view2.userInteraction = YES;
>    transprantImageView.hidden = TRUE;
> }
> ```

}